# passing values to onchange in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am newbie to react. I am having doubt in onchange function. I am having two date fields, "Start" and "End" date. I want to display the "Current Month + year" in "Start Date" like "March 2020" and in "End Date" I want to display the "Month and Year" based of "Start Date". For Example: if user selecting "April 2020" in "Start Date" I want to display from "April 2020 to April 2021" in "End Date". Based on "Start Date" I want to display "End Date". If user selects "May 2020" in start date and I want to display "May 2020" it should not display previous month of May. I know that we want to handle this by using onchange. Same I have achieved in Jquery. Here in react I am struggling to get this done. Below is the code where I got current month and year in drop down list. Could any one can help me with this case. Thanks in advance.

```
 const fareMon = () => {
        const monthList = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
        const currDate = new Date();
        const year = currDate.getFullYear();
        const months = [];
        let currentMonthIndex = currDate.getMonth();
        let yearsToAdd = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < 13; i += 1) {
          if (currentMonthIndex === 12) {
            currentMonthIndex = 0;
            yearsToAdd += 1;
          }
          const futYear = year + yearsToAdd;
          months.push(<option value={`${monthList[currentMonthIndex]} ${futYear}`}>{`${monthList[currentMonthIndex]} ${futYear}`}</option>);
          currentMonthIndex += 1;
        }
        return <>{months}</>;
      };
    Calling function in Drop Down: 

     <Form.Group className={styles.formGroup}>
                              <Form.Control required as="select" name="startDate">
                                <option value="">Months</option>
                                {fareMon()}
                              </Form.Control>
                          </Form.Group>
Below is Jquery code:

function BindFareMonth(targId, currentMonth, selectedYear) {
    var startDate = new Date(selectedYear, (currentMonth - 1), 1);
    var endDate = new Date(selectedYear, (currentMonth + 11), 1);
    $("#" + targId).html("");
    $("#" + targId).append('<option value="0">Select Month</option>');
    while (startDate <= endDate) {
        var ddMopnth = startDate.getMonth() + 1;
        ddMopnth = ddMopnth < 10 ? "0" + ddMopnth : ddMopnth;
        $("#" + targId).append('<option value="' + startDate.getFullYear() + "-" + ddMopnth + "-01" + '">' + monthNames1[$("body").attr("data-culture")][startDate.getMonth()] + " " + startDate.getFullYear() + '</option>');
        startDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth() + 1, 1);
    }
};
```

Comment: Why not use the same while approach to your React code?, Since both codes greatly differ

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to call `fareMon()` and thus update options whenever user selects a date.

Here's list of things you should do

1. Instead of returning the option from `fareMon()` set them as state, So that React can better handle their changes and update them efficiently
2. use `useEffect` with `value` as dependency for calling `fareMon()`, so that it will called every time React detects a change in `value`

```
const foo = props => {
  // Select state
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("")
  // Options state
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fareMon = () => {
      // your code goes here
      // then set the state instead of returning
      setOptions(months)
    }
  }, [value])

  const handleChange = ev => {
    setValue(ev.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <Form.Group className={styles.formGroup}>
      <Form.Control required as="select" name="startDate">
        <option value="">Months</option>
        {options}
      </Form.Control>
    </Form.Group>
  )
}
```